# Python linked list remove

Tags: python

When the remove_from_tail() method is called, the last element in the linked list is removed from the linked list. Your solution to this exercise will be a minimal implementation of the LinkedList class that contains the following methods: **init**(), print_all(), add() and remove_from_tail(). To complete the remove_from_tail() method, it might be useful to create a loop and use a "curr" reference to locate the last element in the list, but at the same time keep a "prev" reference to the previous Node in the chain.  Once you have reached the end of the list, you can set the "next" field of the "prev" pointer to None to remove the last element. You can assume that there will be at least one element in the list when remove_from_tail() is called - however, if there is only one element, then you will need to set head to None when that element is removed.

EDIT:
I have change my code and got things right, however, there are still small things with error, and I can't seems to figure out why. This is my new code:

```
def remove_from_tail(self): 
    current = self.head
    previous = current
    while current.get_next() != None:
        previous = current
        current = current.get_next()
    previous.set_next(None)
    return current.get_data()
```

The error that has to be fixed:[Sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4phE.png)

Comment: What problem are you having with your code?

Comment: The system somehow said this: TypeError: remove_from_tail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'.
I have no idea where I did wrong.

Comment: Where do you call remove_from_tail, @Joker?

Comment: Refer to the sample output that I have edited in the question.

Comment: Well, the error message tells you what the problem is. You have defined `remove_from_tail` with two arguments (`self` and `item`) but when you call it, you are passing only the implicit `self`. From reading the problem description it seems you are intended to remove the last item, so your function does not need to be told what item to remove. Thus you do not need to accept `item` in your function. Of course, you will need to change the logic of your function to actually achieve the desired goal, too.

Comment: Could you please refer to Sample2 and guide my how can I fix my code?

Comment: in your `remove_from_tail` method, you should also include a check for a one-item list before the `while`-loop. I think after that you'll get the correct output for the `100` test case.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sure np, I'll put it in an answer

Answer (score 0):

The while-loop conditional handles only multiple-item lists. Try adding a condition to check for one-item lists before the while loop:

```
# Check for an empty list
  ...

# Check for one-item list
if current.get_next() == None:
    data = current.get_data()
    self.head = None
    return data

# Multi item list
...
```